# Periodic high kernel CPU load?

Tags: c, linux, centos, kernel, cpu-usage

Surprisingly high kernel CPU for programs that normally uses little CPU. Linux machine alternates between states. Most of the time, programs execute normally using low CPU. During a CPU "surge", programs use high kernel CPU using 100% available CPU.

Sample C program and output below.

The machine goes in and out of a weird state roughly every five minutes where some, but not all, programs use high kernel CPU. The CPU "surge" might last a minute then the machine returns to normal state for another 5-10 minutes. Reboot sometimes help but the surges gradually build up over a week until the problem becomes severe enough that another reboot is required. Sometimes a reboot doesn't help and the only temporary fix is to try another reboot.

- CentOS release 6.9
- Dell PowerEdge R630 with 14 CPUs, 32 GB Ram
- Linux 2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64

I was able to reproduce the CPU issue with this sample C program. It runs a shell script that executes a `sleep` for 0.01 second and prints the run time for each of 10 iterations. It runs quickly when the machine is in a normal state and runs slow when the machine is in the abnormal state.

test_system.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n;
    char cmd[100];

    if (argc == 2) {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        n = 1;
    }

    printf("n=%d\n", n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        system("ts=$(date +%s%N) ; sleep 0.01 ; tt=$((($(date +%s%N) - $ts)/1000000)) ; echo \"Time taken: $tt milliseconds\"");
    }
}
```

Here's output when the machine is in a normal state. Most of the CPU is in the user space.

```
$ time test_system 10
n=10
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds

real    0m0.210s
user    0m0.059s
sys     0m0.015s
$
```

Here's output when the machine is experiencing CPU "surge" mode. I added comments where two long pauses occurred. The delays are due to machine being CPU overloaded. The run time is 35.6 sec, 170x longer than normal. The kernel CPU usage for this run is 7.2 sec, a 480x increase from the normal run.

```
$ time test_system 10
n=10
Time taken: 161 milliseconds
Time taken: 406 milliseconds
Time taken: 58 milliseconds
Time taken: 176 milliseconds
Time taken: 189 milliseconds
--- approx. 17 sec delay ---
Time taken: 25 milliseconds
Time taken: 127 milliseconds
Time taken: 82 milliseconds
Time taken: 84 milliseconds
Time taken: 12 milliseconds
--- approx. 17 sec delay ---

real    0m35.641s
user    0m0.077s
sys     0m7.233s
$
```

This [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153466/huge-cpu-load-due-to-high-system-usage/389401#389401) suggests too much memory allocated for I/O buffers can cause this problem because the kernel has to work hard to reclaim memory in order to run programs. But there's no indication of memory swapping or shortage. I ran a separate test of allocating 100 MB memory and don't see delays or high CPU even during the CPU surge.

Any other suggestions on what can cause this behavior?

Here's my latest test program that times `fork()` and `exec()` separately.

test_fork.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define ELAPSED_USEC(t1, t2)  (SEC2USEC((t2).tv_sec - (t1).tv_sec) + (t2).tv_usec - (t1).tv_usec)
#define SEC2USEC(sec)         ((sec)*1000000)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n;
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    struct timezone tz;
    pid_t pid;
    char *shell = "/bin/bash";
    char *shell_cmd;
    int status;

    if (argc == 3) {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        shell_cmd = argv[2];
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s count shell_cmd\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("n=%d shell_cmd=[%s]\n", n, shell_cmd);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        gettimeofday(&start_time, &tz);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
        {   
            fprintf(stderr, "fork failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid > 0)
        {   
            gettimeofday(&end_time, &tz);
            printf("fork: %ld usec, ", ELAPSED_USEC(start_time, end_time));

            gettimeofday(&start_time, &tz);
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            gettimeofday(&end_time, &tz);
            printf("exec: %ld msec\n", ELAPSED_USEC(start_time, end_time)/1000);  // 1 msec = 1000 usec
            //assert(WEXITSTATUS(status) == 123);
        }
        else
        {
            // we are the child
            execl(shell, shell, "-c", shell_cmd, NULL);
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   // exec never returns
        }
    }
}
```

And here are some sample output while machine is in surge state. Only `exec()` uses extra CPU.

```
$ test_fork 10 'exit 123'
n=10 shell_cmd=[exit 123]
fork: 41 usec, exec: 1 msec
fork: 46 usec, exec: 46586 msec
fork: 57 usec, exec: 1 msec
fork: 46 usec, exec: 12 msec
fork: 50 usec, exec: 112 msec
fork: 50 usec, exec: 1 msec
fork: 46 usec, exec: 2 msec
fork: 43 usec, exec: 1 msec
fork: 40 usec, exec: 18 msec
fork: 71 usec, exec: 1 msec

real    0m46.741s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m13.999s
$
```

Comment: Memory shortage, process list full, too many conpeting processes, anything goes...

Comment: It's almost impossible for us to tell what's wrong with your system with so little information... but: Linux 2.6.32? Jesus that is OLD, have you considered upgrading? Specially on that computer. An infinite number of bugs was probably fixed since that version.

Comment: Yes, I already asked for a OS upgrade. But that much is outside of my control.

Comment: There are about 250 copies of a data entry app running on the machine. Users add/modify orders throughout the day. This translates to about 100 database records inserted/updated or deleted per second. Not a heavy load. Again, no indication of memory swapping or shortage.

Comment: Are the 17-second delays reproducible if you `nanosleep()` within your C program, without spawning external processes?

Comment: Regarding the "surges": is the CPU getting periodically throttled because of high core/package temperatures? If the clock frequency drops too low, _really_ low, this might explain why trivial tasks suddenly become so slow, at least in part. (`dmesg`, lm-sensors, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/thermal_throttle/*` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` may be your friends here.) If temperatures seem to be OK but memory might be a problem, you could `swapoff` all of your swap devices/files and wait to see if someone invokes the OOM killer.

Comment: @vicky - I monitor core temps. No problem there. I agree, I need to see if the problem is specific to spawning a shell.

Comment: You will likely have considered this already, but does something interesting show up when you compare the output of `pidstat` (with an interval argument, so that it operates kind of like `top`, rather than `ps`) during a "surge" and immediately after it is over? (If `pidstat` is not available, `diff`ing something like `ps ax -o pid,lstart,etime,time=TOT_CPU_TIME,vsz=MEM__VSZ,rss=MEM__RSS,thcount,nwchan,stat,cmd` might be better than nothing.)

Comment: @vicky - Possible solution. I verified problem is in calling system(). I am testing now with my own version of system() written using fork & exec. It seems to work. Now to put this in production. I also have to do same for popen() next. Both system & popen() equally affected. I'm surprised fork & exec sidesteps the issue. Too good to be true?

Comment: @vicky - Sorry, I spoke too soon. I finally got fork & exec to reproduce the same high CPU usage.

Comment: When you examine other running processes, do they typically undergo the same increase in system time predominantly, as opposed to user-level CPU time? There must be some common denominator among the programs experiencing this funny behavior...

Comment: @vicky - No, only select processes increase CPU. For example, Postgres server is running on same machine. Those processes are not affected. I just checked how often fork() is called by app. Currently at 55/sec. Note: My tests show fork/exec are not causing the strange state. Well, looks that way. It's just that when in the problem state that each system/popen can use up to 6,000x normal CPU. So 55/sec can have effect of 330,000 fork&exec/sec.

Comment: This is surely an interesting problem. So `fork+exec` cause high CPU usage in the test program (just like `system`, `popen`), but not elsewhere? I hope someone can shed some light on us here...

Comment: @vicky - Update: I timed fork and exec separately. Only exec uses the extra CPU. I added new program and results above.

Comment: @Vicky - I found a program using high CPU without fork/exec. I used strace -T and found it has similar unexplained high CPU on open("/dev/sr0", O_RDONLY | O_EXCL | O_NONBLOCK). How is open on CD-ROM related to fork/exec?

Comment: Waiting for upgraded OS install. Might take weeks. I expect that to help.

Comment: Does `O_NONBLOCK` even make any difference for a block device? Anyway, this whole issue is weird. I would think there is a confounding variable behind all of this. Maybe `setrlimit(2)` could help isolate and narrow down potential culprits?

Comment: @vicky - Finally upgraded OS to CentOS 7 Linux 3.10.0 two weeks ago. Seems to have fixed the unusual high kernel CPU usage. I'll wait another month or two to be sure.

Comment: Wow, that's great news! Let's hope that whole mess was just an old kernel bug... :)

Comment: Update: Discovered a second component to the issue. At infrequent random times, the app would attempt many thousands of inserts into database. Almost all attempts failed due to duplicate key. The CPU involved with these attempts was amplified by the kernel issue with the outdated OS. The machine would become unusable. We couldn't see the app activity because the amplified out-of-control kernel CPU usage hid the issue. Since inserts failed there was no evidence of app issue after rebooting. We had to fix the OS first by updating and then we could see/fix the app issue.

Answer (score 1):

Install [dTrace](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux) and run something like the following dTrace script when your system is experiencing the slowdowns:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option quiet

profile:::profile-1001hz
/ arg0 /
{
    @hot[ arg0 ] = count();
}

dtrace:::END
{
    printa( "%@u %a\n", @hot );
}
```

You might have to change the shebang.

Run it when the system is having one of its "episodes" (perhaps with an automatic start based on one of your time-testing programs in your question), let it run for 10-15 seconds (take out the `#pragma D option quiet` if you want to see some details), kill it with `CTRL-C` from the keyboard or `SIGINT` from a process.

The script will then emit all the kernel stack traces it sampled, with the most common coming last - where you can see them.

Those last few kernel stack traces will **tell you where the kernel is spending its time** during the "episodes".

No guessing involved.  No Easter Egg hunts.  You get **TOLD** what's going on.

That script, run on a Solaris 11.4 box in the middle of doing a `zfs send ... | ... zfs receive ...` backup, shows this:

```
   .
   .
   .
1729 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0xcd
1834 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0xe8
1883 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0xf1
1991 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0xbc
1994 unix`wrmsr+0xd
2015 unix`sys_syscall+0x1b9
2089 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0x131
2182 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0x115
2346 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0x1bd
2363 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0x93
2376 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0x1a6
2869 unix`mutex_enter+0x10
3619 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0x135
4223 zfs`zfs_lzjb_compress+0x108
5982 unix`mutex_delay_default+0xa
7480 unix`mutex_delay_default+0x7
8548 unix`bcopy+0x55a
3148971 unix`i86_mwait+0xd
```

Note that the in this example, the vast majority (by three orders of magnitude...) of the time is spent in the idle loop as it's a 24-core server that's currently doing nothing other than the `zfs` backup.  And just about everything else noted is something involving that backup.